# Service area/accessibility analysis from point and avoiding polygon layer

Tags: qgis, network-analysis, service-area

I have a point layer representing a sea bird colony (being a single point is an approximation but effect will be small). I also have a polygon layer of all land masses (from naturalearthdata.com). I want to find the area within a defined foraging range of the colony that can be accessed, with the caveat that birds must travel by sea (i.e. not overlapping land polygons).

Does not need to be extremely precise - as a rough guide let's say the mapped boundary should be in all places within 1km of the "perfect" service area boundary.

I am using QGIS.

Example:
Colony at 56.07810404, -2.64040283 (Lat Lon)
Landmasses from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-land/
Foraging range 230km
Expected output: something like Figure 1 here: https://www.nature.scot/doc/interim-guidance-apportioning-impacts-marine-renewable-developments-breeding-seabird-populations

Comment: Could you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) containing a minimal dataset, especially of your points used, as well as the expected output?

Comment: Is the colony a *single* point? How complex is the land mass data? Have you looked at the `gdistance` R package for routing on grids? This sort of routing is a known-hard problem - how thorough do you need to be? Edit your Q with as much info as possible, and unless asking purely about algorithms, only ask how to do it in one package at a time, or someone will be along shortly to close it...

Comment: One question per Question, please. Offering three solution platforms is three questions.

Comment: Edited OP to address these comments.

Comment: That coordinate point is on land, so by your criteria the birds can't go anywhere. For a 230km range I image a lot of small islands aren't really a problem, but you want to stop the other side of the country being counted (as in the article).

Answer (score 2):

### Use raster cost approach

The advantage of this approach is that it explicitely excludes land areas and still calculates regions behind island correctly (indirect path around islands).

To calculate which points can be reached in a certain time (and, if we suppose constant speed, this also corresponds to a certain distance), you can use a raster cost approach: Create a raster that has a prohibitive high value for land mass and a constant, low value (like 0) for sea. Then use GRASS tool `r.walk.points`.

You might combine the result with "conventional" (vector) buffers to limit the result to a certain, fixed distance.

*[North Euboean Gulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Euboean_Gulf) with land/islands in gray, distances from the blue dot in the in viridis color ramp: the longer the distance (cost) over the sea, the darker the color. The opposite (north_eastern) side of Euboea island is in dark violet: long distance (over sea) to reach as you have to navigate around the whole northern part of the island and back (to the north inside the gulf, around the north coast and back south along the north-eastern coast), even if be beeline, it is much closer than the northern coast of the island, which, however, is easier to reach (less distance) over sea:*
[image]

*Converting the output raster to contour polygons, showing the area reachable by sea in a certain time:*

[image]

### Prepare data

Get a vector file with the landmass (e.g. type `world` in the coordinates bar) and rasterize it. Set `A Fixed value to burn` to a high value like 1.000.000.000 and leave `nodata value` empty. You get a raster with the landmass in white (=1.000.000.000) and sea in black (=0).

[image]

### Run `r.walk.points`

Go to Menu Processing > Toolbar > r.walk.points. Set twice the raster created above as input and select your point layer for `Start points` and run the tool.

The output raster layer `Cumulative cost` shows you the cost to reach each cell from the start points. As the landmass has a prohibitive cost, it gets high values. So we can set a freely definable `max` value to make these areas disappear: all regions that are too far away to reach, including all land masses.

Be aware: measuring distances, be sure to reflect which CRS you use and if length distortions for your region of interest is acceptable!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Buffer your points (colonies) with the desired distance
2. Create the Difference (Buffer minus landmass layer)
3. Multipart to single parts
4. Use Select by location: SIngle parts intersect with features from colonies layer: the selected polygons are those you're looking for.

*Be sure to create the colonies layer in a CRS appropriate for distance measurements in your area of interest! EPSG:3857 and generally any Mercator projection does not give correct distance measurements.*

*Screenshot: Red dots = colonies; yellow polygons = selected part of single parts layer (step 4) - the blue parts (Denmark, northern Germany) are not connected and can't be reached without crossing land:*
[image]