# Connecting points with closest points (lines) avoiding polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometric-network, shortest-path

How can I connect multiple points with the closest line or point of the network avoiding polygon (land or sea) in QGIS?

There are over 4000 points that have to be connected this way so it would be good to have automated process.

I've tried to use 'distance to nearest hub (line to hub)' function but there is no functionality to avoid polygon and connection to the nearest point can be with several lines.

[image: Point connection scheme]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/drawing of what you want to do?

Comment: See here if it can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/438385/88814

Comment: @Babel It helped a bit, thanks! First, I've created a cumulative cost raster layer for all points. Then created paths (lines) connecting (red) points with the closest green point using least-cost path plugin. Unfortunately, it connects all red points first and then connects to a green point.