# Creating buffer avoiding polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know how to generate areas in which ships can go X distance?

I'm looking for a tool similar to a Buffer, but that takes into account the avoidance of a polygon and adds up the distance by having to round the polygon.

To give an example:
A ship travelling 10 km from point 1 will not be able to reach point A because the distance travelled around the land polygon (in grey in the image) is more than 10 km (buffer in red).

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create the `difference` between your buffers and the land feature?

Comment: No, because if I do it this way it would be as if the boat leaving point 1 follows the red arrow to point A when the real distance travelled is the length of the blue arrow.

Comment: So you're asking how to create isochrone maps?

Comment: Yes, but at sea

Comment: This isn't a task for vector GIS. You want to model this as a raster, probably taking hazards and channels into account. Note that the Question would be clearer if you used conventional symbology (blue water/tan or pale yellow land) and annotated the desired path on the image.

Comment: Could you split your shoreline with the points then measure those lengths?  An actual shipping route wouldn't follow the shoreline in such detail so perhaps you could buffer it, simplify the results and then convert that to a line and recalculate lengths for crude estimates.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439618/88814

Comment: Thank you all, I will do it as Babel indicated with the r.wolk.points function of GRASS.