# How to find shortest distance routes from a point to a line without overlapping on buildings?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to find a plugin/function that can automatically find and sketch shortest-distance routes between a Multipoint layer and a MultiLineString layer. But the catch is that they are supposed to avoid the polygons that lie between them.

[image: reference picture]

Legend:

1. Black line: Road (MultiLineString layer)
2. Brown polygon: Building
3. Yellow point: Current point
   of traveller (Multipoint layer)

I have only been able to find solutions for shortest distance between 2 points but not for those which cannot accommodate overlaps.

Comment: Your request requires a road network

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. Do you know what steps I should be taking after converting the black lines into a road network?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too general, more details and specific questions on individual problems are needed.

Comment: Sure, I need routes to be drawn automatically from each yellow circle to the black line while avoiding any polygons that might be between them(routes can be sketched in any manner as long as it doesn't touch the polygons) . I'm a beginner in QGIS so I can't seem to find any viable function that might be of help. Please do let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Is your example above typical of the numbers of points/buildings/lines that you need to deal with, or is it a simplified version? Obviously the problem is going to get ~exponentially more difficult the more points/buildings/lines you have to deal with. Also, you may be worth asking the question on say the Math StackExchange site, as it's at its essence an optimisation problem.

Comment: Raster coast approach would be a possibility, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439618/88814